# execluding specific nodemanagers while running a job

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am using **hadoop-2.7.3**. How i can i **exclude specific nodemanagers** only for some jobs. I tried some configurations but it was  applicable to resourcemanager level not with nodemanager.Is it possble to achieve this by any mapreduce job level property.

**example:** I want to run job1 in a nodemanager group1(5 servers), job2 in nodemanager group2(other 5servers)

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude nodes if you're using Capacity Scheduler.  The feature is called Node labels.  Refer to [YARN Node Labels](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/NodeLabel.html) for more information.